# Which function here has been deprecated?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.11.0, and this short toggle code works well as long as I am loading jquery-migrate. When I don't load the jquery-migrate file, I don't see any js errors, but no text is shown on the page. What's breaking it?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".toggle_content").hide();
    $("h4.toggle").toggle(function () {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    });

    $("h4.toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).find(".toggle_icon").toggleClass("fa-rotate-270 norotate");
        $(this).next(".toggle_content").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: `.toggle` has been deprecated from that kind of use for a long while http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deprecated function here is `toggle()`. It still exists, but it no longer accepts two functions to be executed alternately as your code attempts. In your case, you can replace it with `toggleClass`:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".toggle_content").hide();
    $("h4.toggle").click(function(){
        $(this)
            .toggleClass("clicked")
            .find(".toggle_icon").toggleClass("fa-rotate-270 norotate").end()
            .next(".toggle_content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```